# react native async getting data when running app first time

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have two components, in first components storing data in asyncstorage, in second component display data, when install app and save data does not get data from asyncstorage, when open app second time data are displayed.

```
storeData = async (item, messave, messrem) => {
    const checkarary = this.state.favorite;
    if(checkarary.some(e => e.name === item.name)) {
        const value = this.state.favorite;
        const position = value.filter((lists) => lists.id !== item.id);
        this.setState({
            favorite: position
        }, () => {
            try {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('favoriti', JSON.stringify(this.state.favorite), () => {
                    Toast.show({
                        text: messrem,
                        buttonText: "Okay",
                        duration: 3000,
                        type: "danger"
                    });                  
                });
            } catch (error) {
            }
        });    
    } else {
        this.setState({
            favorite: [...this.state.favorite, item]
        }, () => {
            try {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('favoriti', JSON.stringify(this.state.favorite), () => {
                    // AsyncStorage.getItem('favoriti', (err, result) => {
                    //     console.log(result);
                    // });
                    Toast.show({
                        text: messave,
                        buttonText: "Okay",
                        duration: 3000,
                        type: "success"
                    });
                });
            } catch (error) {
            }
        }); 

    } 
};
```

Getting data in second component

```
 _retrieveData = async () => {
try {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('favoriti').then((value) => {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(value);
    this.setState({ favorite: parsed })
  })
} catch (error) {
}
};

componentDidMount() {
 this._retrieveData();
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    loading: false,
  })
 }, 2000)
};

componentDidUpdate() {
   this._retrieveData();
};
```

How fix this issue, is there some solution. Can I  set Item and reload app when install app or somthing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
componentWillMount() {
 this._retrieveData();
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    loading: false,
  })
 }, 2000)
};
```

instead of

```
componentDidMount() {
 this._retrieveData();
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    loading: false,
  })
 }, 2000)
};
```

As componentWillMount is called after constructor is called for class and componentDidMount is called after screen is once rendered.